# docker run -v <dir> vs Dockerfile's VOLUME <dir>

Tags: docker

Is there any relationship between mounting volume with `docker run -v` command and Dockerfile's `VOLUME` instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-v` option can be used to bind a directory on the host to the container, but the `VOLUME` instruction cannot. Other than that they are two different ways for making a volume available in the container.

Both instructions create a mount point in the container, but only `-v` can actually mount anything there.

See:
http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume and
http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume
for more in-depth descriptions of what both do.